# How to dynamicly get a multi dimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

My code just populates the last array in the array $workshops

my loop function populates array $workshops, like so

```
    while (ECSE_purchase::have_products()) {
                ECSE_purchase::the_product();
                $prodid = ECSE_purchase_product::get_the_ID();
                $workshop_data = ETICKETDATA::get_workshop_details_helper($prodid);
                $workshops = array();  
 if($prodid == 565) {
............
} else { 
$workshopsTmp = array();
                            $workshopsTmp['workshop_barcode'] = $data['workshop_barcode'];
                            $workshopsTmp['workshop_id'] = ECSE_purchase_product::get_the_ID();
                            $workshopsTmp['workshop_title'] = ECSE_purchase_product::get_the_name();
                            $workshopsTmp['workshop_time'] = $workshop_data['time'];
                            $workshopsTmp['workshop_room'] = $workshop_data['room'];
                            $workshopsTmp['workshop_num_of_tickets'] = ECSE_purchase_product::get_the_QTY();
                            $workshops[] = $workshopsTmp;
}
```

But here i just get the last array and not like this:

```
$workshops = array(array('workshop_barcode' => '0101010101',
                                'workshop_id' => '589',
                                'workshop_title' => 'Swimming',
                                'workshop_time' => '12:00',
                                'workshop_room' => 'Room 1',
                                'workshop_num_of_tickets' => '2'),
                            array('workshop_barcode' => '03030303003',
                                'workshop_id' => '568',
                                'workshop_title' => 'Running',
                                'workshop_time' => '15:00',
                                'workshop_room' => 'Room 3',
                                'workshop_num_of_tickets' => '3'),
                            array('workshop_barcode' => '0505050505',
                                'workshop_id' => '570',
                                'workshop_title' => 'Biking',
                                'workshop_time' => '16:00',
                                'workshop_room' => 'Room 2',
                                'workshop_num_of_tickets' => '2'));
```

Any pointers appreciated.

regards,

just edit the loop

Comment: Tag your question with the language you're using.

Comment: What exactly is you problem? What are you trying to do?

Comment: You need to show more of your loop code. The shown sample doesnt look to be the culprit.

Comment: Are you setting or getting the array in the lower code example?

Comment: did you initalize the $workshops variable before the loop?

Comment: just edit my question with the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep redefining your initial array. Try putting $workshops array before while loop

```
$workshops = array();  

while (ECSE_purchase::have_products()) {
                ECSE_purchase::the_product();
                $prodid = ECSE_purchase_product::get_the_ID();
                $workshop_data = ETICKETDATA::get_workshop_details_helper($prodid);

 if($prodid == 565) {
............
} else { 
$workshopsTmp = array();
                            $workshopsTmp['workshop_barcode'] = $data['workshop_barcode'];
                            $workshopsTmp['workshop_id'] = ECSE_purchase_product::get_the_ID();
                            $workshopsTmp['workshop_title'] = ECSE_purchase_product::get_the_name();
                            $workshopsTmp['workshop_time'] = $workshop_data['time'];
                            $workshopsTmp['workshop_room'] = $workshop_data['room'];
                            $workshopsTmp['workshop_num_of_tickets'] = ECSE_purchase_product::get_the_QTY();
                            $workshops[] = $workshopsTmp;
}
```

Comment: AARGggh, pff you are so right. Starring at a part of the code for too long. Tx